# UTF_8 string reading from file counting special character as string length

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, non-ascii-characters

I have a text file which contains a string per line something like

```
String1
String2
String3
String4
String5
String6
```

In my java code i am reading it simply as

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader((new InputStreamReader(in, Charsets.UTF_8)))) 

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
 }
```

However i got a surprised when i did a line.length() as the length for all of my strings are coming one character extra! In the above case 8 instead of 7. I copied the text file contents and saved as a simple text file and when i ran the above code on the new file the length came out correct.

When i did a diff on the two same file i saw that my original file had this encoding.

```
<U+FEFF>String1^MString2^MString3^MString4^MString5^MString6
```

I believe my java code is taking these special characters into account when giving me the length?

Is it because i am using Charsets.UTF_8? What changes can i make so that my java code ignore these characters when giving me the length.

Comment: `^M` is `\r` in the Linux world, so it's not encoding, but line endings. What OS are you using to read the file, and what OS produced the contents of the file?

Comment: Hi Brian, The file is actually a csv file which is generated by MS excel and the OS is Mac OS. I am actually thinking its probably safer to use a CSV parser from apache commons to take care of all this heavy lifting.

Comment: That would probably fix your issue. I've used OpenCSV in the past, so that could be a starting point.